# A very basic ANOVA question

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have just started to study stats and I had a fairly basic question. Say I had three sets of measurements from three different groups. How do I run an ANOVA on the measurements. For example,

```
Group | Temp measurement 1 | Temp measurement 2 | Temp measurement 3 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
I     | 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1| 3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4| 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1|
II    | 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2| 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5| 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2|  
III   | 3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3| 8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8| 3,3,3,4,3,3,3,4,3,3|
```

The hypothetical data was collected from three regions (of similar physical characteristics) denoted by Group I, II and III. A temperature sensor was used to measure temperature at each of these regions. Temp Measurement 1 shows temperature measured at baseline, Temp Measurement 2 shows temperature collected after an event A and Temp Measurement 3 shows temperature collected after an event B. 10 temperature points were measured at baseline and after events A and B. These data points were collected 1 second apart and were collected right at the start of an event (or baseline).

Can I run a ANOVA with 3-repeated measurements to find if a difference exists between Temp measurements within each subject? If so, should I take the mean value of each temperature measurement set? I am so lost with this analysis. Can someone help and point me to some good reading material on the subject?

Edit: Added some more details of the hypothetical data shown. I hope the added information clears things up

Comment: What do the individual numbers in `Group` and `Temp` mean? How are they related? A little bit of background would help.

Comment: As you'll probably figure out when learning ANOVA, the design of the experiment plays a large role in determining the subsequent analytic approach. In order for us to help you, you will need to provide us with much more information about this example of yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design you have described here is a mixed-design ANOVA, because you have one between-subjects factor (group) and one within-subjects factor (temp measured at different times).

From https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/mixed-anova-using-spss-statistics.php:

> A mixed ANOVA compares the mean differences between groups that have
>   been split on two "factors" (also known as independent variables),
>   where one factor is a "within-subjects" factor and the other factor is
>   a "between-subjects" factor...The primary purpose of a mixed ANOVA is
>   to understand if there is an interaction between these two factors on
>   the dependent variable.

So, when interpreting your results, you will first be looking to see if there is a significant interaction between group and time, i.e., if the changes in temperature over time differ for the three separate groups.